# VideoView taking too long to start video from url

Tags: android, android-videoview

Hi I am trying to run video from url. I  call the dynamic videos by passing url. Most of the time it takes too long to start a video. videos file size vary form 3-10 mb. I have tried on  minimum  size but still the problem is there. there is no problem in connection i am using Wifi network with good speed.
 I have user below code to run the video

```
        try{

            Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
            videoview.setVideoURI(video);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        videoview.requestFocus();
        videoview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                int height = mp.getVideoHeight();
                int width = mp.getVideoWidth();
                changeori(height, width);


            }
        });

public void changeori(int h,int w)
{
    if(h>w)
    {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        videoview.start();
    }
    else
    {
       setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
       videoview.start();
    }
```

}

Comment: hey, did you find any solution for this? i am facing the same problem..